# RepositoryItemReader skipping chunks

Tags: spring-batch

I am using RepositoryItemReader to read records from the database and using Chunk oriented process these records. I am using 100 as page size and commit interval.
    Query for the reader has "timestamp" in where condition and this date will be get updated by chunk processing when a chunk of 100 get the process and committed. The problem I am running is let's say I have 986 records that need's to be read and updated the date in a chunk of size 100 (1-100). All works as expected first time but when it picks up the second chunk it is processing 201-300, not 101-200 which is unexpected. This pattern continues, the third time it is picking up 501-600 and so on. The pattern is skipping 100 first time and 200 second time and so on. Is my update and commit of chunks causing this? Please advise how to fix this, so it can process all the records.

Spring batch version:   4.0.1.RELEASE

```
Code:
 @Autowired
    private MpImportRepository importRepo;
@Autowired
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager;
   @Autowired
    private MpImportRepository importRepo;

 @Bean
    @StepScope
    public RepositoryItemReader<MpImport> importDataReader() {
           RepositoryItemReader<MpImport> reader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
           reader.setPageSize(100);
           reader.setRepository(importRepo);
           reader.setMethodName("findAllImportedMissingPersons");
           reader.setSort(Collections.singletonMap("missingDate", Sort.Direction.ASC));
        return reader;
    }  

@Bean
    @Qualifier("mpDataExtractAndSaveToYrstJob")
    public Job mpDataExtractAndSaveToYrstJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("mpDataExtractAndSaveToYrstJob")               
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(jobCompletionListener)
                .flow(mpDataExtractAndSaveToYrstStep())
                .end().build();

 @Bean
    @Qualifier("mpDataExtractAndSaveToYrstStep")
    public Step mpDataExtractAndSaveToYrstStep() {
           return stepBuilderFactory.get("mpDataExtractAndSaveToYrstStep")
                   .<VMpHotfilesDailyExtract, MpImport> chunk(Integer.parseInt(100))
                   .reader(hotFilesReader())              
                   .processor(hotFilesProcessor())                   
                   .writer(importDataWriter())
                   .transactionManager(jpaTransactionManager)
                   .listener(mpdataExtractStepListener)
                   .listener(chunkCompletionListener)
                   .build();
    }   

 @Bean
    @StepScope
    public RepositoryItemWriter<MpImport> importDataWriter() {
        RepositoryItemWriter<MpImport> writer = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
          writer.setRepository(importRepo);
          writer.setMethodName("save");
       return writer;
    }
```

Comment: Probably this happens because you change the sort key while processing records. Have you tried to **not** update the `timestamp` filed and see if it the reader correctly reads all records?

Comment: yep I think is dangerous to change the data you are using for sorting at runtime.

Comment: Yes, I tested by not updating the timestamp and all works great. So I am writing a solution not to update timestamp and see how that goes. Thanks all for the advice/comments.